# How to verify whether the header has the property or not using Spring Integration Expression?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to verify whether the header has a specific property or not using Spring Integration Expression. Please see below code:

```
<int:router input-channel="PQAdditionalContactHistory-Format-Response-Router" expression="headers.get(pqAdditionalContactHistoryJob)" ignore-send-failures="true"> 
        <int:mapping value="PQAdditionalContactHistory" channel="PQContactHistory-PQAdditionalContactHistory-Format-Response"/>

            </int:router>
```

In the above code, I need to verify whether the property `pqAdditionalContactHistoryJob` exists in the header or not.If so it needs to be routed based on the value.
Can anyone please provide an expression to evaluate my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Elvis operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-elvis) is your friend.

```
expression="headers['pqAdditionalContactHistoryJob'] ?: 'nullChannel'"
```

Comment: When I use the above expression, I am getting `org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: headers.get(pqAdditionalContactHistoryJob) ?: nullChannel` since the property `pqAdditionalContactHistoryJob` is not available in the Headers I believe.So, I need to check if that property exists or not firstly and then retrieve its value. It would be great if you can provide a suitable expression.

Comment: That's what the elvis operator `:?` does; however, `nullchannel` should be a literal - try `headers.get(pqAdditionalContactHistoryJob) ?: 'nullChannel'`.

Comment: However, if you only have one route, depending on whether the header is present, why not just use a `<filter... expression=headers['foo'] != null" />` ?

Comment: Your header key needs to be a literal too... Use `headers['pqAdditionalContactHistoryJob'] ?: 'nullChannel'`. I just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. I forgot to put single quotes on `nullChannel` earlier.